# parse host output with regex

Tags: regex

We have dig output which looks like

```
Trying "google.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 177.39.160.253
Address: 177.39.160.253#53
Aliases: 

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52549
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 6

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     245 IN  A   216.58.202.46
google.com.     245 IN  A   216.58.202.47

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            16060   IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            16060   IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net. 13518   IN  A   192.5.6.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 23554   IN  A   192.12.94.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 24306   IN  AAAA    2001:502:1ca1::30
g.gtld-servers.net. 13443   IN  AAAA    2001:503:eea3::30
k.gtld-servers.net. 2284    IN  A   192.52.178.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 10638   IN  AAAA    2001:503:d2d::30

Received 400 bytes from 177.39.160.253#53 in 306 ms
```

I need to write regex which will return 216.58.202.46 and 216.58.202.47

Right now I'm doing it using 2 regexes:

At first I'm taking content of the answer section with

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:[\s\S]*?\n\n
```

Then I'm parsing answer with

```
.*IN[\t *]A[\t *](?P<output>[\S]*)\n
```

Can I achieve same functionality with 1 regular expression?
Thanks.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/2Np9Mr/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow! Even with the regex101 explanation I still don't quite get all you did ... I'll need some time to figure out everything

Comment: @Esteban: If it works for OP, I will post with explanations. Илья, does it work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works on his exampe for sure, only thing I changed on the regex was the `ADDITIONAL SECTION` to `ANSWER SECTION`, but all in all, it did what he wants to. Thanks for taking time to make the explanation

Comment: Yes, https://regex101.com/r/2Np9Mr/2. I did not pay attention to that bit.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. It works exactly as required. Can you please explain? lol

Comment: Sure, just a sec, was busy posting another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex based on the `\G` operator that matches either the position at the start of a string, or the location after a successful match.

```
(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|;; ANSWER SECTION:)(?:(?!\R{2}).)*? IN +A +\K\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Np9Mr/2).

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - an inline DOTALL modifier that makes `.` match line break chars, too (now, it matches any chars)
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|;; ANSWER SECTION:)` - either the location after the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`, the start of string position is subtracted with the negative lookahead) or a literal string `;; ANSWER SECTION:`
- `(?:(?!\R{2}).)*?` - a tempered greedy token matching any char (`.`) that is not a starting point for a double line break sequence (`\R{2}`, `\R` matches any linebreak sequence), as few times as possible, as `*?` is a lazy quantifier
- `IN +A +` - space, `IN`, 1+ spaces, `A`, 1+ spaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.